# How to determine if two strings have only one different character in a functional style with iterators?

Tags: string, rust, char, iterable

I need to write a function that will check if two `String`s differ in exactly one character in sequential way, i.e. only `diff("aba", "abc") == true`, `diff("aab", "cab") == false`, length of strings is equal).

I wrote the code in an imperative style, but it seems ugly and I want to write it in functional style with iterator.

I suppose it should be something with `s1.chars()..enumerate()` + some closure, that detects one different character in two strings.

```
fn has_one_difference(s1: &String, s2: &String) -> bool {
    let mut diff_chars_limit = false;
    let mut s1_chars = s1.chars();
    let mut s2_chars = s2.chars();

    for index in 0..s1.len() {
        if s1_chars.nth(index).unwrap() != s2_chars.nth(index).unwrap() {
            if diff_chars_limit {
                return false
            } else {
                diff_chars_limit = true
            }
        }
    }

    return diff_chars_limit;
}
```

I get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/libcore/option.rs:345:21
```

on the last character of string iteration.

Comment: It seems to me you have forgot to subtract 1 from the length of the string: (s1.len() - 1)[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fd946d57241b80db557f5d29a60265d)

Comment: I don't get why one of your examples is false. They both differ in exactly one char and are both equally long. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan 0..x is inclusive for 0 and exclusif for x, the problem is that `s1_chars.nth` mut the iterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I corrected your imperative code to

- remove the extremely inefficient index-based access into the character iterators,
- remove the crash if `s1` is longer but otherwise equal to `s2` and replace this with the same "ignore tail of longer string" behavior that your code exhibits the other way around,
- use `str` instead of `String` since there's pretty much never a good reason to pass a `&String` to a function, and
- fix some minor style issues; in particular adding semicolons to returns, but using tail-return expression without return. This is more idiomatic Rust.

It looks like this:

```
fn has_one_difference(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> bool {
    let mut found_one_difference = false;

    for (c1, c2) in s1.chars().zip(s2.chars()) {
        if c1 != c2 {
            if found_one_difference {
                return false;
            } else {
                found_one_difference = true
            }
        }
    }

    found_one_difference
}
```

Now for the functional version, I would simply compose an iterator and see if I can call `next()` on it twice:

```
fn has_one_difference_functional(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> bool {
    // An iterator over different char pairs.
    let mut iter = s1.chars().zip(s2.chars())
        .filter(|(c1, c2)| c1 != c2);

    // First call to next() must succeed (one difference), second must fail.   
    iter.next().is_some() && iter.next().is_none()
}
```

This isn't fully functional, but I think it's overall the best combination of conciseness and readability. A simple fully functional version would call `count()` on the composed iterator and compare that to 1, but that is not short-circuiting and thus less efficient than need be. A more efficient version can be written with `try_fold`, but that loses readability due to complexity, so I would only consider it for a `has_n_differences` function.

Comment: `s1.chars()
        .zip(s2.chars())
        .filter(|(c1, c2)| c1 != c2)
        .nth(1)
        .is_none()`

Comment: @Stargateur Nice, but it doesn't distinguish "no differences" from "one difference".

Comment: But that outside the scope of the function anyway ?

Comment: @Stargateur Not as originally written, no.

Comment: *call `next()` on it twice* — this doesn't have guaranteed behavior unless you call `fuse()`. I guess this is handled by the `is_some` short-circuiting, but it still raised my eyebrows at first.

Comment: *that is not short-circuiting* — use `take`?: `s1.chars().zip(s2.chars()).filter(|(c1, c2)| c1 != c2).take(2).count() == 1`

Comment: "use `take`" - clever!

Comment: Guys, i really appreciate for clear explanation and func code sample. Thx for help!